# How to repeat whitespace

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to get a string like the following one:

> `[====    ]`

For that purpose I am using this code:

```
'[' + '='.repeat (4) + ' '.repeat (4) + ']'
```

... but I just get `[==== ]`; that is, all spaces are squashed into one. I checked this code in the google chrome console, and indeed `' '.repeat(25)` produces only one space. How do I make `repeat` really produce more than one space?

I do not find anything related in [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).

Comment: Seems this question causes a lot of confusion. I faced this issue while designing a small extension to google chrome hence I did not even bother to test my source in other browsers and did not give enough background to see that this question is actually about a user-visible HTML page and not about an internal JS data structure.

Sorry for the confusion, all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers collapse multiple whitespace, in order to force it not to you can use [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Therefore, in your case you can use

```
'&nbsp;'.repeat(4)
```

(Its arguable that a debug console *shouldn't* collapse the whitespace, but in your case it seems it does)

Comment: But why spaces cannot be `repeat`ed?

Comment: @IonicăBizău That is all explained in the wiki link in my answer under "non-collapsing behavior"

Comment: Hmm - interesting.  I would expect the console to display the string as-is rather than collapsing the whitespace as happens in the DOM, but it seems whitespace is also collapsed in console output.

Comment: ...And I got it. I used `<tt>` where as it happens I meant `<pre>`.

Comment: @Jamiec Actually they **can** be repeated! See my answer.

Comment: [IE console displays the string as-is, I wonder if there's a bug in Chrome here.](http://imgur.com/Nl6J85o)

Comment: This is the accepted answer. It answers the question how to repeat the spaces so that they are displayed on a web page outside of `<pre>`. The other answer does not address the actual question, though is interesting by itself.

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue of Chrome's developer tools. Empty spaces *can* be repeated, but they are displayed as one character, which is wrong:

> [image]

You can check the result like this:

```
(' ' + ' ').length
// => 2
```

Here is an example from Node.js REPL:

[image]

In conclusion, your code does work, but Google Chrome's console doesnt display the result correctly.

If you're talking about the displaying in HTML elements that don't have monospace fonts, use [**@Jamiec**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec)'s solution, using [non-breaking spaces](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Non-breaking_space):

```
'[' + '='.repeat (4) + '&nbsp;'.repeat(4) + ']'
```

---

As [**@James Thorpe**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791010/james-thorpe) this *was* a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516989) which got fixed. Probably we will get the fix when updating the browser version.

Comment: This is an HTML thing, not a javascript thing. Clearly javascript sees 2 spaces as 2 in length. HTML (and by extension a browser console) will/may only *display* one string

Comment: @Jamiec I think the browser console should display the string as-is - see my comment on your answer.  I wonder if this behaviour in chrome is documented anywhere

Comment: @Jamiec Question is about JavaScript: *I checked this code in the google chrome console, and indeed ' '.repeat(25) produces only one space.*. The HTML thing is obvious, but the OP asks about the Chrome's console.

Comment: @Jamiec Firefox, for example, show us the string with the correct number of spaces.

Comment: It is indeed a bug.  [Here is the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516989).  Fixed towards the end of August.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you! Added it to answer.

Comment: FWIW, Chrome updated on my machine this morning to version 46.0.2490.71 m - the bug is fixed in this version.