# Strange String Behaviour with Spaces in Chrome Javascript Console

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome

I cannot recreate this behaviour in the SO snippet engine, but I'm coming across some pretty funky string manipulation behaviour in Chrome (v46).

Have a look at this screenshot of the Chrome JavaScript console:

[image: chrome example]

To my mind, the result of the slice should be `(   Here`. That is, a bracket and then three spaces. Not a bracket and then one space, which is what it is currently offering me.

I checked the exact same commands in Firefox, which yield the results I was expecting:

[image: firefox example]

Can any one think of an explanation for the difference in output? Am I being dense?

**Update**

In regards to this being a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970636/how-to-repeat-whitespace), I believe this question does two things differently:

- It is much clearer in its query
- It asks why the phenomena occurs, rather than how to solve the problem

Comment: I think it could be a bug. The simplest way to reproduce is to enter `'"(   Here'`. The console will reply: `""(   Here"` (my first snippet has 3 spaces, but it renders as only one)

Comment: if you copy the result from the chrome js console, and paste you will see that the spaces will be there. X)

Comment: You're right @JoelRamosMichaliszen, can you elaborate on why? It's making debugging difficult.

Comment: maybe something like CR LF in the console, i dont really know, but is curious,  I will find the answer X)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970636/how-to-repeat-whitespace)

Comment: @w0lf I can see they are the same issue, but I think this one is a bit clearer. My personal feeling is it should be kept open.

Comment: That was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516989) which is marked as _fixed_. But I've no idea in which version...

Answer (score 3):

This is just a DevTools issue, which most probably has been addressed with the following patch http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=201091

It's about collapsing multiple white characters, as HTML rendering is done by default. The mentioned patch forces rendering using `white-space: pre`.

Comment: I like this answer (+1) because it provides an explanation. But I still don't see why the console output is adopting collapsing spaces from inline HTML rendering. After all, if I type `"<div style="width:10px, height:10px; background-color:green;"></div>"` into the console, it doesn't offer me a green square.

Comment: Well, I didn't check DevTools' source code, but I assume, that the provided text is converted to a text node, so < > and other HTML special chars are treated as pure text and this gets inserted into DevTools' document structure. So, HTML rendering still applies, only special chars are "escaped".

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear and my last comment was cut short. I know that multiple spaces collapse in HTML. But I don't see why that should effect console output. As far as I'm concerned, the console should not be mimicking HTML rendering behaviours. The console may be using a TextNode to display, but that doesn't mean that this is not technically a bug in Chrome. I can't imagine this would ever be the intended behaviour in a debugging console.

Comment: I never said it wasn't a bug. This is a bug, well maybe more a usability bug, because DevTools became less usable to the devs. The bug has been addressed. Another fact is that the DevTools in Chrome are built using HTML+CSS+JS+probably some internal stuff exposed to JS, so the root cause of the bug was, that the author of the feature didn't apply rendering rules using `white-space: pre`.

Comment: I think we're in agreement then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issues actually. Even I tried with Chrome v46, the spaces are merged in the devtools, meaning the output/view looks like there is only one space, but there is actually 3 space characters present. Check the below snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem but with the value coming from a textbox / input. This bug is occurring in the console but also in the browser on Chrome, Edge and Opera on Win10 and on iOS 12, iOS 15 and Android Chrome. However, FireFox console and browser still show the spaces accurately and lets you trim the value to fix it.
This is seems to be a bug with Chrome's javascript engine. In the example below, I'm trying to trim the user's input data they enter in a text box / input. Only Firefox sees and lets me trim the leading and trailing spaces off the text string and in the bottom example lets the code update the UI. Run this code and enter 5 spaces followed by 5 letter a's followed by 5 more spaces:

```
<input id="textbox" type="email" 
  onblur="alert('|' + this.value + ' & ' + this.value.trim() + '|')">
```

Only FireFox shows the spaces in the alert. Same if you manually get the value in the console via document.getElementById('textbox').value like the op is experiencing.

I discovered this bug when the onblur was the following and working in FireFox:

```
onblur="this.value = this.value.trim();"
```

UPDATE: I found the "bug". The Chrome engine and iOS engines notice that the input is type="email" so it trims leading and trailing spaces automatically for you BUT only when you interact with it via JavaScript. However, all those browsers DO NOT refresh the UI and don't allow you to do it either unless you first change the value from say

```
"   a@aa.com    "
```

to "b" then to "a@aa.com".
Therefore, the following fixes it so it now works as expected in all major browsers:

```
<input id="email" type="email" 
onblur="let x = this.value; 
  this.value = ''; 
  this.value = x.trim();">
```

This is an annoying and ugly bug. Hoping someone here can suggest a cleaner fix / work around.

Answer (score -1):

Don't fool yourself: Chrome's behaviour is correct. It's just the font used in the debug console which makes contiguous blanks seem thinner. You can proof it by checking `string.slice(1).length`.